# Changing size and color of labels in Bokeh high level charts

Tags: python-2.7, charts, bokeh, chord-diagram

Is there a way to change or manipulate the font size and color of the labels in Bokeh high level charts like the [Chord chart](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/chord_chart.html)?

Bokeh provides options to change the background color etc, but I cannot seem to find any means to tweak the labels either in Bokeh or in css.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the text size and color you have to alter the glyphs inside the chord chart renderers. The renderer in index position 3 is the text glyph renderer so you can set the font size and color there.

```
chord_from_df = Chord(source_data, source="name_x", target="name_y", value="value")
chord_from_df.renderers[3].glyph.text_font_size['value'] = '12pt'
chord_from_df.renderers[3].glyph.text_color = '#FF0000'
show(chord_from_df)
```